# Calculate and return the average of only the positive values in the list

Tags: python

Ignore all the negative elements, and only use positive elements to calculate average.

```
ave_pos([3, -3, 4, 0, 2, -1]) = 3
```

Here is what I have so far and I am completely lost on why it's not working!

```
def ave_pos(nums):
    avg = 0 
    for x in nums:
       if x > 0:
           avg = avg + x
    return avg
```

Comment: in your method you are calculating sum not the average.

Comment: You have summed all the positive numbers. The sum is not the average; you are missing the division step (count the number of values that are greater than 0 too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to extract all the positive numbers into another list.

```
def mean_positive(L):
    # Get all positive numbers into another list
    pos_only = [x for x in L if x > 0]
    if pos_only:
        return sum(pos_only) /  len(pos_only)
    raise ValueError('No postive numbers in input')
```

Answer (score 1):

use filter and sum for this:-

```
a = [3, -3, 4, 0, 2, -1]
apositive = filter(lambda x:x>0, a)
sum(apositive)/len(apositive)
```

Comment: While this works fine in Python 2, in Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator (a `filter` object) which you can't call `len` on (nor iterate over more than once). Your code would work if you use `list(filter(...))`, but a list comprehension might be more natural.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are just adding up all the positive elements, not computing their average. Your variable `avg` ends up with the sum of all positive elements. To get the average, you need to divide the sum by how many there were. Here's a modification of your code that works:

```
def ave_pos(nums):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for x in nums:
       if x > 0:
           total += x
           count += 1
    return float(total) / count
```

As you can see, it maintains the running total and count separately, and divides them out at the end. If you're using Python 2, then you need the call to `float` otherwise the division will round down to the next integer. In Python 3 this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more and your problem can be solved by yourself: you just need to divide the sum by the number of the positive elements:

```
def ave_pos(nums):
    avg = 0
    pos = 0
    for x in nums:
        if x > 0:
            pos = pos + 1
            avg = avg + x
    avg = avg / pos
    return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

the formula to calculate average is 
total_sum / number_of_elements

Use a count variable to count no of positive element and return sum/count

```
count =0;
sum = 0 
for x in nums:
   if x > 0:
       sum = sum + x
       count = count + 1
return avg/count
```